# Why is React.js not loading HTML code when using marked library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown

I am trying to build a markdown editor for which I am using the [Marked library](https://github.com/chjj/marked) 
My Code doesn't show any error but doesn't render the html at all.

Code :

```js
class TextArea extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.value}} />
  );
 }
}

class Markdown extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   value: " "
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }
 handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <TextArea value={marked(this.state.value,{sanitize: true})} />
   </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Markdown />, document.getElementById("markdown"));
```

The input I have given to the code is in markdown format

```html
Heading
=======

Sub-heading
-----------

### Another deeper heading

Paragraphs are separated
by a blank line.

Leave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a  
line break

Text attributes *italic*, **bold**,
`monospace`, ~~strikethrough~~ .

Shopping list:

* apples
* oranges
* pears
Numbered list:

1. apples
2. oranges
3. pears

The rain---not the reign---in
Spain.
```

and the output give by marked library is

```html
<h1 id="heading">Heading</h1> <h2 id="sub-heading">Sub-heading</h2> <h3 id="another-deeper-heading">Another deeper heading</h3> <p>Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.</p> <p>Leave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a<br>line break</p> <p>Text attributes <em>italic</em>, <strong>bold</strong>, <code>monospace</code>, <del>strikethrough</del> .</p> <p>Shopping list:</p> <ul> <li>apples</li> <li>oranges</li> <li><p>pears Numbered list:</p> </li> <li><p>apples</p> </li> <li>oranges</li> <li>pears</li> </ul> <p>The rain---not the reign---in Spain.</p>
```

But It doesn't render the HTML
Please Help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.state.value` should be `this.props.value` because you are sending `value` in as a prop of `TextArea`:

```
class TextArea extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.value}} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: On changing the code and running it it still shows no output.https://codepen.io/kartikey21/pen/LzKGmx?editors=0011 link for code

Comment: You changed the wrong one :)  Inside `TextArea` make the change, not outside

Comment: Please check the code in the link : codepen.io/kartikey21/pen/LzKGmx?editors=0011

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me in the codepen :)  If I put ` ## header` in the `textarea`, I get a big `Header` value in the `TextArea`