# Why React returns "Object() is not a function" when using marked library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, markdown

I'm making a markdown editor using [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) library like this `<div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: marked('Rendered by **marked**.''></div>` but get TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

Found two relevant posts on SO; [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934216/why-is-react-js-not-loading-html-code-when-using-marked-library) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686523/using-marked-in-react) I'm using the same syntax as the answers but I get a TypeError. In both posts they used ReactDOM.render() method in the end. Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from'redux';
import { marked } from "marked";

// Redux
const ADD = "ADD";

const addText = (text) => {
  return {
  type: ADD,
  text: text
  }
};

const textReducer = (state = {text: ''}, action) => { 
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD:
    return Object.assign({},state, { text: action.text })
    default:
    return state
  }
};

const store = createStore(textReducer);

// React
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    /*this.state = {
      input : ''
    }*/
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

};

  handleChange(e){
    /*this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    })*/

    this.props.addText(e.target.value)
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App-header">
       <textarea id="editor" value={this.props.text} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
       <div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: marked('Rendered by **marked**.') } }></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};


// React-Redux
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    text: state.text
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addText: (text) => { 
      dispatch(addText(text))
    }
  }
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

// eslint-disable-next-line
export default class AppWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

The markdown text suppose to be rendered as html in preview element but instead I get TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

UPDATE: apparently redux was not setup properly and was set to an array instead of object. I fixed that but I still get the same error.

Comment: I also made a Codesandbox version of this App [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2p0wqnjv0n), in case you want to see the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, problem was I imported marked as named `import {import {marked} from 'marked'` instead of import as default like this `import marked from 'marked'`